# VB6 Fast Performance Database

Tags: mysql, vb6

Sorry for asking a little bit too common question, but I need the advice of an experienced user for solving this problem. Related to some extend with my previous question, I installed MySQL server on my computer running WindowsXP.
I managed to connect my VB6 Application with an ODBC driver but the time for instance for adding records was much greater than by adding them to an MSAccess DB.
I did this because i needed to get rid of the 1GB file size limitation.
Is it normal such a difference and could something be done in order to improve performance?

Comment: We don't know how fast you were inserting into Access, nor do we know how much slower MySQL is. You also didn't say whether you configured MySQL or not (nor did you mention what version you used). MySQL out of the box is extremely slow because it's designed to work with old machines as well.

Comment: I am using MySQL Workbench 5.2. and the server is version 5.5.20. I took some measures but don't remember the exct figures. The difference was about 5-10 times in favour of Access. I did some configuration but keeping in mind your comment i will spend more time on that. thanx!

Comment: Also, if the queries were at all complex or the tables large then MySQL will depend on the indexes. Have you set up indexes after putting the tables into MySQL?

Comment: Try MyISAM for tables engine. Try performing inserts/updates in a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

- Access / JetDB is an in-process database

There is no separate data server with JetDB - the data you insert doesn't have to be marshalled to another process, which will make it faster.

If you want an in-process database that isn't JetDB, try [SQLite](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=6893) which does not have the artificial memory limits of JetDB.

- Try using socket connections

Or "[Named Pipes](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-1/specifying-socket/)" on Windows - this may be faster than using TCP connections.